# UILabel.text doesn't change from NSString (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I'm trying to change `name`(`UILabel`).text to `nameString`(`NSString`) but it does not present it on the screen (it does change - is it the value when I debug and it the correct value).

Code:

```
NSString *namesString = [self.names objectAtIndex:i];
infoWindow.storeAddressLabel.text = namesString;
```

Note: if I type:

```
infoWindow.storeAddressLabel.text=@"someText";
```

It works

Does anybody know why is it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you do it in main thread? Is `info.Window.storeAddressLabel` nil ?

Comment: Just try `infoWindow.storeAddressLabel.text = @"Hard Coded Text";`  and see what happen,

Comment: Couple of reasons. 1 - names array is empty, 2 - There is errors in your code there. sef.names should be self.names. Also your setting a variable nameString and setting your label to a variable called namesString. 3 - considering you wrote this and didnt copy and paste, then your label may not be hooked up

Comment: @Larme Yes, on the main thread, and no, it's not nil (it's the correct string)

Comment: @Aamir yes it works, that really weird

Comment: @Devster101 Everything is fine. infoWindow.storeAddressLabel.text=@"TEST" works so that can't be any of that.

Comment: then i must say `self.names` is empty or retiring `nil`

Comment: @Aamir It not, when I debug (NSLog) the object at index "i" it prints the correct object

Comment: try [infoWindow.storeAddressLabel setText: namesString];

Comment: @Avaan tries it, still the same problem

Comment: add NSLog(@"%@", namesString); and what it prints....  Looks like namesString is empty.

Comment: You mention it "prints the correct object". Is that object actually a `NSString`? If hard coding the string works then there is something wrong with `namesString`

Comment: Copy all your code on here. From all the comments it has to be a problem with your array. Maybe your names array is nil. I need to see more code to see what went wrong

Answer (score 2):

You're referencing two different variables. On the 1st line you define `nameString`, and then on the next line you set using `namesString` with an extra `s`

Comment: My bad, It's just a typing mistake on this forum, not the problem :)

Comment: What is the actual code you're running then? I have a feeling there's something missing from your two examples

Comment: @Yhper COPY THE CODE. dont rephrase it or retype it, **copy it**.

Answer (score 1):

If `infoWindow.storeAddressLabel.text=@"someText";` works, then `storeAddressLabel` object isn't nil. The only possibility can be that the string being returned from the code `NSString *namesString=[self.names objectAtIndex:i];` is being returned nil. Please check and verify.

Thanks.

Comment: Checked it, and it don't

Comment: @Yhper Can you log the value ? Just to be sure. check if you are not getting any unexpected string value which is not getting rendered in the UILabel view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this see what happens,

```
NSString *nameString=[sef.names objectAtIndex:i];

if( nameString!=nil && nameString.length >0){
   NSLog(@"nameString %@",nameString);
   infoWindow.storeAddressLabel.text=namesString;
}
else{
   infoWindow.storeAddressLabel.text=@"nameString variable was nil so I am being set as label text";
}
```

Comment: you must check `nameString!=nil` before checking its `nameString.length > 0`, its a big crash.

Comment: It enters the "if" and not the "else"

Comment: @Yhper it crashes if `nameString` is `nil`, then its like `nil.length`.

Comment: @Aamir sorry my bad!

Comment: @Aamir but it isn't (it's not nil)

Comment: what you get when you log nameString value?

Comment: @Yhper are you sure that you are on doing all this in the main thread??

Comment: ok then try this, `[infoWindow.storeAddressLabel setText:[self.names objectAtIndex:i]];`

Comment: @Aamir It makes no difference

Comment: @satheeshwaran I do. And if I type a string (=@"test";) it works so that's not a threads problem or an IBOutlet problem

Comment: That nil check is redundant. If you check `string.length > 0` on a nil object, it will still be 0 and won't crash.

Answer (score 0):

In correction to above code which contains many bugs, i have written following answer:

```
NSString *nameString = [sef.names objectAtIndex:i];

if(nameString)
{
   infoWindow.storeAddressLabel.text = nameString;
}
else
{
   infoWindow.storeAddressLabel.text = @"nameString variable was nil so I am being set as label text";
}
```

Comment: Same thing, it enters the "if" and not the "else"

Comment: it enters "else " if `nameString` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a class method to assign the **text** property - *(check for nil first of course as stringWithString: must be passed a non-nil NSString)*

```
infoWindow.storeAddressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)[self.names objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your **namesString** is not nil then it should be displayed..
try like this,

```
NSString *namesString = [self.names objectAtIndex:i];
infoWindow.storeAddressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",namesString];
```